# Pushing a comment to GitLab repository,just a test comment not a meaningful code.How?

Tags: gitlab, push, git-commit

I want to push a comment to GitLab repository,just a test comment not a meaningful code.How?
I want to add "test comment" to some file or inside the code
I used git commit -m "test comment", it took it then I wrote git push but it said 'Pipeline has failed', I am new to gitlab I don't know how to fix it.